# CF - Mobile Managed Gestures

Tags: compact-framework, scroll, gestures

Im looking for a nice demo/sample using Windows Mobile Managed Gestures.

I have a main view that contains a single panel.
Every item in the panel is another panel containing pictureBox and a label.

I would like to implement scrooling (finger flicking) to avoid using thin scroolers.

Are the Windows Mobile Managed Gestures the right solution to get this working, if so can some one provide me with a begginers demo?

I downloaded the source code from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/gestureswm/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3438 but i would need a simple example using this source.

Also a question ... does this work only on 6.5?
Even if i got this working is there a way to support this in 6.0 ?

thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at either of [the two](https://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/WebCastEventDetails.aspx?culture=en-US&EventID=1032422141&CountryCode=US) [webcasts](http://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/EventDetail.aspx?EventID=1032422150&Culture=en-US) covering the library for usage examples?

As far as backward compatibility, so this is a WinMo 6.5-only feature because it uses the [Gesture APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee220920.aspx) which only exist in WinMo 6.5.